# The death of Dr. Smith

Tags: riddle, mathematics

Dr. Smith, having recently finished his PhD, called some of his friends that had just finished their doctorates and masters to comemorate in a trip to his uncle's country house.

During the party, the lights went out for roughly 10 minutes, and a loud noise could be heard. When the lights returned, Dr. Smith was the only one unaccounted for.

They found him dead in his room, with a gun on the floor and a bloodstained note stating, in his own handwriting, Smith's final problem:

> There is a number that's 2 and 1, and neither 
>   This number is 0 and 1, and both 
>   This number is not easy to find, but do keep in mind that 
>   To determine this number is to find the identity 
>   This number should tell you who killed me.

The five friends that Smith called were named Ana, Eric, David, Gideon and Tatiana; among the staff only the butler, Mortimer, was present that day.

To give the friends peace of mind until the police solve this case, tell me: "Who killed Dr. Smith?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that

> Dr. Smith committed suicide.

Argument:

> * The bloodstained note hints at the imaginary unit $i$.
>  * It essentially states "The murderer is i", that is, "I am the murderer".
>  * The imaginary unit satisfies $i^2+1=0$ (with $2$ and $1$ and $0$).
>  * 0 and 1 are the coordinates of $i$ in the complex plane.
>  * In mathematics, the letters $i$ and $I$ are often used to denote the identity (for instance, in linear algebra $I$ is the identity matrix).

Comment: That's not exactly the reasoning I had in mind but it works, and the answer is indeed correct! I hope this wasn't too easy (or too bad or something like that, for my first riddle here) :)

Comment: The puzzle is fine, in particular the red herrings Ana, Eric, David, Gideon and Tatiana and Mortimer.  Perhaps you can also post the resoning you had in mind (as a separate answer)?

Answer (score 5):

The answer was

> that Dr. Smith killed himself, the number was i

Because

> There is a number that's 2 and 1, and neither (It's 2-dimensional (complex), 1-dimensional (imaginary), and not actually 2 or 1.)
> This number is 0 and 1, and both (It can be represented as $(0;1)$)
> This number is not easy to find, but do keep in mind that (Complex)
> To determine this number is to find the identity (If you represent a complex number as a matrix, its determinant will be $1$ )